# Loop invariant of simple while loop

Tags: loops, invariants, loop-invariant

I saw an example program which sets every value in an array to 0:

```
int a[n]; int i = 0;
while(i < n) {
    a[i] = 0;
    i++;
}
```

It said that part of the loop invariant was `0<=i<n`. However, after the loop is finished terminating, i will equal n. Am i correct in saying that this is then not part of the loop invariant? If so, what should it be replaced with?
The full invariant was `For All j (0<= j < i --> a[i] = 0) & 0 <= i < n)`

Comment: The complete loop invariant is usually false after a loop. Sometimes achieving that state is the point of the loop. Sometimes, as here, a part of the loop invariant holds true also immediately after the loop, where that is the point.

Answer (score 0):

The loop invariant must hold on loop entry and be preserved by every iteration, including the last iteration.

Therefore the loop invariant should be `0 <= i <= n`

To support my claim, I offer as evidence your program translated into the automatically verified language Microsoft Dafny:

`method Main(a:array<int>) 
   requires a != null
   modifies a
   ensures forall j :: 0 <= j < a.Length ==> a[j] == 0
{
  var i:int := 0;
  while(i < a.Length)
     invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
     invariant forall j :: (0 <= j < i ==> a[j] == 0) 
  {
    a[i] := 0;
    i := i+1;
  }
}`

You can check that this program does indeed verify by running it in the [online version of Dafny](http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/UcJw).